# How to create notification panel in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, reactstrap

I'm trying to create notification panel somewhat similar to shown in below image :

[image]

I tried using collapse in Navbar but the problem is when, i click notification icon it expands whole Navbar.
In another solution , i tried using custom dropdown but not able to set the width of dropdown list.
What can be used for notification panel? Please suggest .

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried. Just adding the requirements won't help.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code,To How to create notification panel in react?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { MDBNotification } from "mdbreact";

class Notification extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MDBNotification
        autohide={3000} // by default = ∞ ms
        bodyClassName="p-5 font-weight-bold white-text"
        className="stylish-color-dark"
        closeClassName="blue-grey-text"
        fade
        icon="bell"
        iconClassName="blue-grey-text"
        message="Hello, world! This is a toast message."
        show
        text="11 mins ago"
        title="Bootstrap"
        titleClassName="elegant-color-dark white-text"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Notification;
```

I hope this code will be useful for you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/atapas/notifyme

```
<NotifyMe
  data={data}
  storageKey='notific_key'
  notific_key='timestamp'
  notific_value='update'
  heading='Notification Alerts'
  sortedByKey={false}
  showDate={true}
  size={64}
  color="yellow"
/>
```